# Codeigniter: Upload/Save Image to Database

Tags: php, image, file, codeigniter, upload

I'm trying to create a user profile edit form on a Codeigniter project with the ability to upload a profile image. I'd like allow the upload to go through when the user clicks the submit button. I have no problems with the form (no errors), but I do not see any image on the uploads folder I set up. Any help to get the upload working would be greatly appreciated.

Controller (User Edit/Insert Values to Database)

```
public function update_edit($id) 
 {   

     $config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/profilepics';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
     $config['max_size'] = 250;
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     $this->upload->do_upload('profile_img_path');
     $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();

     $image = $data_upload_files[full_path]; 
 //input data
 $data = array(
   'user_name' => $this->input->post('user_name'), 
   'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
   'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'), 
   'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
   'city' => $this->input->post('city'), 
   'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
   'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
   'date_edited' => $this->input->post('today'),
   'profile_img_path' => $image 
 ); 
 $this->user_model->update_account($id,$data); 

 //send a confirmation of user account update
 redirect('/');
```

}

Controller to access the form

```
public function update_account()  

 { 

  $id = $this->uri->segment(3); 
  $data['user_profile'] = $this->user_model->get_user_profile($id);
  //only profile owner can access
  if (!$this->uri->segment(3))
   { 
     redirect('404'); 
   } 


  if ($this->is_logged_in()) 
  {  
    if ($this->is_logged_user()) 
    { 

   //update views
   $this->load->view('components/top'); 
   $this->load->view('interact/form/user/edit',$data);  
   $this->load->view('components/bottom'); 
    } 
   else 
    { 
     redirect('403'); 
    } 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    redirect('403');  
  } 
 }
```

The View

```
   <div id="page">  
     <div class="container"> 

       <div class="row"> 

    <h3>Edit Your Account</h3>


   <?php foreach ($user_profile as $user): ?>


<form id="edit_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . "users/update_edit/" . $user->user_id; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label>Enter a new username: *</label>
    <p>yloko.com/users/user_profile/<?php echo $user->user_name; ?>  </p>
    <br/> 
    <input type="text" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $user->user_name; ?>">     

     <label >Enter a new email*</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $user->email; ?>" >

    <label >First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $user->first_name; ?>" >

     <label >Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $user->last_name; ?>" >

     <label >City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $user->city; ?>" >

     <label >Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $user->country; ?>" >


    <label >Description</label>     
    <textarea name="description"><?php echo $user->description; ?></textarea>

     <!--INPUT-->
     <?php echo $user->profile_img_path; ?>
     <input name = "profile_img_path" type="file" class="input-xlarge" id = "profile_img_path" />

    <!--submit button-->    
    <input type="hidden" name="today" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" >   
    <input type="submit" value="Update">     

</form> 
 <?php endforeach; ?> 
  <a href="<?=site_url('/')?>">Back</a>
  <br/> 

    </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/profilepics';
verify this,
you should create the uploads folder with the root directory

and the form tag has to have attribute
 enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code after library is being loaded.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('profile_img_path')) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    echo $error['error'];
}
```

Let us know what exact error you are getting.

Comment: This is what I'm getting: 

Message: Use of undefined constant full_path - assumed 'full_path' 
Filename: controllers/users.php

Line Number: 290. Looks like I need to put the single quote markers for the full_path.

Comment: This helped me point the error. Just made the fix and it's working properly now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> You should include enctype in form

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

```
<form id="edit_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . "users/update_edit/" . $user->user_id; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Forgot to put that part in. However, when I tried it out it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffreyTeruel could you please update your post then accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

`$config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/profilepics';` points to a folder in the filesystem, which you probably have no write access to. Use a relative path like `$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/profilepics';` (`./` being the current directory). Also make sure the folder(s) exist and you have write access to it.